# Different methodologies for teaching to students and their sources

Tags: scripture, upanishads, taittirya-upanishad

I have heard there are 20+ methodologies mentioned in some upanishads like Taittiriya about how to impart education/learning to students some go like:

1. samvAda / discussion
2. sambhAShana / group discussion
3. Practical demonstration
4. Debate etc etc

Can somebody shed some light on this? And if there are some scriptures that delineate these.

Comment: Good question! Vedic teaching methods, role of teacher (Guru), evaluation system etc. are interesting to know.